# Do the incompressible Navier-Stokes Equations apply to incompressible fluids or incompressible flows?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, density, flow, navier-stokes

As far as I understand an incompressible fluid is one where the density is constant and an incompressible flow is one where the material derivative of density is constant ($\frac{D\rho}{Dt}=0$). Both result in the same condition - that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0 $ everywhere ($\mathbf{u}$ is the velocity field). Does this mean that the incompressible Navier stokes should apply both to incompressible fluids and more generally to incompressible flows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Wikipedia Stokes Navier Equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) states:

> The incompressible momentum Navier–Stokes equation results from the following assumptions on the Cauchy stress tensor:
>
> The stress is Galileian invariant: it does not depend directly on the flow velocity, but only on spatial derivatives of the flow velocity. So the stress variable is the tensor gradient.
>
> The fluid is assumed to be isotropic, as with gases and simple liquids, and consequently $V $ is an isotropic tensor.

Incompressible flow does not imply that the fluid itself is incompressible. Under the right conditions, even compressible fluids can – to good approximation – be modelled as an incompressible flow.

Incompressible flow implies that the density remains constant within a parcel of fluid that moves with the flow velocity.

Reading through the pretty comprehensive article might be of help.

Another site which deals with their application is: [Navier Stokes equations](https://www.comsol.com/multiphysics/navier-stokes-equations) and seems to cover both compressible  and incompressible flows, allied with the equation of continuity.